# gRPC requests using Jmeter

Tags: api, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, grpc

is there a way to test gRPC with Jmeter ? 
I would like it in Jmeter since it will enable covering both functional and load with the same tool.

anyone with Jmeter plugin development experience that can help estimate the work and effort ?

Thanks
Ronen